# I can't add new "datetime" fields to my TypeORM entity

Tags: typeorm

I defined an entity like that:

```
import { Column, CreateDateColumn, Entity, Index, JoinColumn, ManyToOne, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm'

@Entity({name: 'entity'})
export class Entity {

  public constructor(
    dateTime: string
  ) {
    this.dateTime = dateTime
  }

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  public id: number

  @Index('index_date_time')
  @Column({name: 'date_time', type: 'datetime'})
  public dateTime: string

  @CreateDateColumn()
  public created: string

}
```

When adding a new "datetime" column to this entity, like that:

```
  @Index('index_date_time2')
  @Column({name: 'date_time2', type: 'datetime'})
  public dateTime: string
```

I get stuck with this error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: QueryFailedError:
> ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE: Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00
> 00:00:00' for column 'date_time2'

The strange thing is that I already have a "datetime" field in the same entity.

I tried to do this with other entities, but I have the same problem with all of them. It's like I was able to add "datetime" fields up to a certain point, and now I can't add any more.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Date` as the type for your dateTime field

Comment: It was not working either. I had to clear the table to solve the problem. So it was related to the data already in the table.

Comment: oh, okay 
Glad you solved it 